# Any recommendation for dependency search for MySQL

Tags: mysql

Trying to find a way to find dependencies on MySQL objects. 
E.g function is used in views, triggers, stored procedures, other functions. Any suggestion for queries or tools which can do it?

---

I created stored procedures to load dependencies of each type, table, routine and view. 
Below is the one for table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sys_get_table_depends` (
p_object_name varchar(256)
)
BEGIN

SELECT 
    information_schema.routines.routine_type as `object_type`
    ,information_schema.routines.routine_name as `object_name`
    ,information_schema.routines.routine_definition as `object_definition`
FROM   information_schema.tables
 INNER
  JOIN information_schema.routines
    ON routines.routine_definition LIKE Concat('% ', tables.table_name, ' %') OR
       routines.routine_definition LIKE Concat('%.', tables.table_name, ' %') OR
       routines.routine_definition LIKE Concat('%`', tables.table_name, '`%')
where tables.table_name = p_object_name
UNION
SELECT 
    'trigger' as `object_type`
    ,concat(information_schema.triggers.event_object_table, information_schema.triggers.trigger_name) as `object_name`
    ,information_schema.triggers.ACTION_STATEMENT as `object_definition`
FROM   information_schema.tables
 INNER
  JOIN information_schema.triggers
    ON triggers.ACTION_STATEMENT LIKE Concat('% ', tables.table_name, ' %') OR
       triggers.ACTION_STATEMENT LIKE Concat('%.', tables.table_name, ' %') OR
       triggers.ACTION_STATEMENT LIKE Concat('%`', tables.table_name, '`%')
where tables.table_name = p_object_name
UNION
SELECT 
    'view' as `object_type`
    ,information_schema.views.table_name as `object_name`
    ,information_schema.views.view_definition as `object_definition`
FROM   information_schema.tables
 INNER
  JOIN information_schema.views
    ON views.view_definition LIKE Concat('% ', tables.table_name, ' %') OR
       views.view_definition LIKE Concat('%.', tables.table_name, ' %') OR
       views.view_definition LIKE Concat('%`', tables.table_name, '`%')
where tables.table_name = p_object_name;
END
```

But looks like not all object definitions are stored in information_schema. Some are has empty definition field. My guess it is in MySQL schema. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
SELECT *
FROM   information_schema.tables
 INNER
  JOIN information_schema.routines
    ON routines.routine_definition LIKE Concat('%', tables.table_name, '%');
```

Comment: Thanks gvee, 
I'll put below stored procedures which may serve the purpose.

Comment: Arrghh.. As soon as stackoverflow will allow me to publish it.